# Como criar coluna virtual para colocar resultado sequencial por categoria - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma tabela que tem 3 colunas

- Categoria, Nome e Soma (além da coluna ID_teste - Sequencial Chave primária)
  Preciso sabe como criar uma consulta para gerar uma coluna virtual com uma sequência, em função da
  1º Categoria
  2º Soma
  3º Nome

No caso, seria algo como
[Como deve ficar o resultado da consulta]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQO8D.jpg

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.29, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: teste
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.29

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `teste`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teste`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `id_teste` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `soma` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_teste`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


--
-- Dumping data for table `teste`
--

LOCK TABLES `teste` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `teste` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `teste` VALUES (1,'CATEGORIA1','Edward Branch',200),(2,'CATEGORIA1','Matthew Rodriguez',20),(3,'CATEGORIA1','Christopher Anderson',30),(4,'CATEGORIA1','Emily Duke',50),(5,'CATEGORIA1','Devon Howard',450),(6,'CATEGORIA1','Brittany Wong',300),(7,'CATEGORIA1','Mr. Joseph Avery',120),(8,'CATEGORIA1','Mary Diaz',100),(9,'CATEGORIA1','Lisa Glover',30),(10,'CATEGORIA1','Patricia Adams',31),(11,'CATEGORIA1','Raymond Long',60),(12,'CATEGORIA1','Christy Martinez',55),(13,'CATEGORIA1','Kelsey Zamora',80),(14,'CATEGORIA1','Anthony Reeves',45),(15,'CATEGORIA1','Mr. Shane Baker MD',30),(16,'CATEGORIA1','Peter Mcconnell',100),(17,'CATEGORIA1','Sarah Miller',10),(18,'CATEGORIA1','Eugene Delgado',15),(19,'CATEGORIA1','Aaron Bass',45),(20,'CATEGORIA1','Nathan Williams',53),(21,'CATEGORIA1','Michael Fox',23),(22,'CATEGORIA1','Christopher Tate',89),(23,'CATEGORIA1','Debbie Lewis',57),(24,'CATEGORIA2','William Johnson MD',1),(25,'CATEGORIA2','Jessica Lester',2),(26,'CATEGORIA2','Kevin Cochran',3),(27,'CATEGORIA2','Nathan Alexander',10),(28,'CATEGORIA2','Patrick Jimenez',50),(29,'CATEGORIA2','Tiffany Harris',40),(30,'CATEGORIA2','Christopher Alexander',9),(31,'CATEGORIA2','John Gardner',80),(32,'CATEGORIA2','Mrs. Deborah Wilkinson DDS',45),(33,'CATEGORIA3','Tiffany Petty',63),(34,'CATEGORIA3','Eileen Brown',78),(35,'CATEGORIA3','Melissa Armstrong',60),(36,'CATEGORIA3','Louis Thompson',86),(37,'CATEGORIA3','Brian Hoffman',95),(38,'CATEGORIA3','Monica Downs',87),(39,'CATEGORIA3','Michael Collins',32),(40,'CATEGORIA3','Margaret Fernandez',64),(41,'CATEGORIA3','Carolyn Moore',21),(42,'CATEGORIA3','Brandy Robertson',85),(43,'CATEGORIA3','Jill Bennett',12),(44,'CATEGORIA3','Gabrielle Jones',15),(45,'CATEGORIA4','Russell Kline',65),(46,'CATEGORIA4','David Martinez',45),(47,'CATEGORIA4','Jason Mccarty',52),(48,'CATEGORIA4','Dustin Miller',23),(49,'CATEGORIA4','Kevin Mckenzie',32),(50,'CATEGORIA4','Joshua Perez',98),(51,'CATEGORIA4','Christina Johnson',89),(52,'CATEGORIA4','Rhonda Cooper',78),(53,'CATEGORIA4','Eric Robinson',85),(54,'CATEGORIA4','Carlos Hansen',74),(55,'CATEGORIA4','Michael Simpson',41),(56,'CATEGORIA4','Michael White',52),(57,'CATEGORIA4','Candice Chaney',63),(58,'CATEGORIA4','Jeremy Bryant',32),(59,'CATEGORIA4','Mr. Matthew Underwood',64),(60,'CATEGORIA4','Mrs. Sherri Nixon',92),(61,'CATEGORIA4','Derek Brown',75);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `teste` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2022-10-11 15:50:11
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: É possível mostrar diretamente a imagem no post sem necessidade de link para redirecionar.

Comment: Como sou novato, essa foi a maneira que o site deixou eu postar. Obrigado

Comment: Alguém tem o conhecimento para me ajudar nessa demanda?